# Drawing a Polygon with R's C/C++ API and Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm currently trying to rewrite an R script in a package in C++ for performance increases. This package can read coordinates of points, colors and some other data from files and does some calculation on it. Finally this data is used to produce many polygons and write it into a pdf file.

This process is too slow in R, so I decided to let C++ with Rcpp do it. I'm done with the calculation part (though I could not parallelise a key for loop, but that's another topic) but I currently do not get any performance increases because I have to call R's graphics::polygon function from C++ code which needs a huge amount of time.

My problem starts there. I've tried to write a method to plot my polygons without calling R code. Therefor I looked into the R source. The graphics package itself does not allow me to use its headers but I could at least take a look at the source code. R's source include directory contains many useful headers which would help me, such as Graphics.h or Rgraphics.h, but these are internal headers and not installed. The only option for me is to work around the original polygon method and to use R_ext/GraphicsEngine.h.
There I found a method called "GEPolygon" with 5 arguments.

```
void GEPolygon(int n, double *x, double *y, const pGEcontext gc, pGEDevDesc dd);
```

It is obvious what the first 3 arguments mean. By looking into the source code of the graphics package I found out what to pass for the last 2 as shown below in my method.

```
void polygonplot(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, String col, String 
border, double lwd, int lty){
  //found in graphics.c
  const void *vmax = vmaxget();

  pGEDevDesc device = GEcurrentDevice();
  int n = x.length();

  R_GE_gcontext gc;
  gc.lty = lty;
  gc.lwd = lwd;
  gc.col = R_GE_str2col(border.get_cstring());
  gc.fill = R_GE_str2col(col.get_cstring());
  //convert NumericVector to double*
  double xx[n], yy[n];

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    xx[i] = x[i];
    yy[i] = y[i];
    // probably converting coordinates, but how?
    // xx[i] = GEtoDeviceWidth(x[i], GE_NDC, device);
    // yy[i] = GEtoDeviceHeight(y[i], GE_NDC, device);
  }
  GEPolygon(n, xx, yy, &gc, device);
  vmaxset(vmax);
}
```

That's all I found out by now. Seems to be good so far, at least for the compiler. After building the package an example script executes the package's functions. The 260th call produces an error in German (as my language is set to German): "unzulässiges Zeilenende", which can be translated as "inadmissible line ending" (haven't found anything useful on the internet about it). The execution stops and nothing else is printed. Even if I attach gdb I don't get any other information. It definitely occurs within the call to "GEPolygon" and should be related to one or both of the last 2 arguments passed. Another problem should be the coordinates, as they are converted in the graphics package's polygon function (see here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bfe73ecd848198cb9b68427cec7e70c40f96bd72/src/library/graphics/src/plot.c#L2012)
I'ld be pleased to read a solution for my problems or even a totally different approach.

I used https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bfe73ecd848198cb9b68427cec7e70c40f96bd72/src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c#L2818 and other files from this repository and I have many many questions to undocumented source code.

If anyone could help me with printing polygons directly from C++ code please do it.

Thanks in advance,
expeehaa

Comment: If you are using C++ and want answers in C++ then don't use the C tag. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @Toby I used it because afaik this API by R is written in C. But I understand your point and will remove it.

Comment: Great. FYI I couldn't see anything exclusively C++-specific in the code you show but you mention you are writing C++, thus I imagine you'll want answers in C++ and this is where the difference for tags normally lies :)

Comment: What makes you think you can just inject C++ code into C functions of the Base R engine?

Comment: idk. I haven't done much with C++ so far but it seems to be possible. And as I can include those header files it should be the easiest solution to my problem. But if you say I should not try, how should I do that otherwise? As you might see I unfortunately do not have enough knowledge and time to write polygons to a GraphicsDevice on my own.

Comment: I think the references to source code have fallen out of date. I took a guess at which lines you were referring to & made the links more permanent by adding a commit ref. Please feel free to revert if I guessed wrong